# Extracting links with xpathSApply

Tags: xml, r

I am currently using a function that employs the XML `readHTMLTable` function and instead of displaying the table contents shows the html links instead. I am using in the line of code this function to get the hyperlinks.

```
y <- xpathSApply(x, './a', xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

My problem is that some of the links are encased in `<strong>` tags and this function does not return the link. How can I modify it to return the link with or without the `<strong>` tags?

Sorry for the basic question but the getNodeSet help file is not very beginner friendly, and I am not sure what exactly I need to search for to solve this.

Comment: any chance you can post a URL or data file sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [*descendant-or-self* axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) -or using the abbreviated syntax `//`- to get the links whether or not they have parent element `<strong>` :

```
y <- xpathSApply(x, './/a', xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Appreciate the link to the help file also!